# UV Unwrapping problem, texture fits oddly

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm very new to this, and I've had this problem with two totally different models.

Why does the sideways texture continue past the seam? What I want is for the sideways texture to simply be in the top section, but it overlaps onto the vertical texture's area. What am I missing?

The knife blade above is a disaster, but this handle problem seems like it should really easy to solve. Appreciate it if someone could help out.

[image: Knife handle and uv unwrap]

Comment: I think you are assuming that because the UV map appears horizontal on one part because it is wider than it is tall on your screen, that it is also a horizontal portion of the knife. This is not so. A circle in 3-D can have a UV map that looks like a star.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Should the horizontal texture not sit where I've seamed it? How do I make it do so and not go past it?

Comment: “Texture“ is the image. There is only one texture involved here. The seam of the UV map should probably be around the four shorter edges of the handle, plus one edge down the side, thus making it rather like a tin can in the way it unfolds. However, the topology of the handle seems rather strange. Are you trying to make the handle look as if it’s made of multiple pieces of wood stuck together, or just one piece?

Comment: Two pieces stuck together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the subdivision modifier.

Here is an object without a Subdivision modifier.
[image]

And here is the same model, with a Subdivision modifier.
[image]

The UVs you have created is according to the original mesh, not the subdivided one.

I'd like to point out a related issue in terms of how topology affects UVs when subdivided.

Here's the original mesh
[image]

And here's the subdivided one. As you can see, the texture gets weird stretching issues.

[image]

To solve -

A. **Apply the Subdivision modifier, then unwrap the model** - Gives you exact control. You can dissolve extra loops afterwards if you wish.

B. OR **Create uniform quad topology** - This option won't give you exact control, but it virtually eliminates stretching issues, and let's you retain the modifier if you wish

[image]